# How can I preserve a dynamically created Drawable after device rotation?

Tags: android, drawable, android-dialogfragment

I'm having a problem figuring out how to restore a dynamically-created Drawable I've loaded into a DialogFragment after an orientation change. When I want to display the dialog, I instantiate the DialogFragment and set the drawable as such:

```
DialogStrokeOrder dialog = DialogStrokeOrder.newInstance(gKanjiDiagram);
dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_STROKE_ORDER);
```

`gKanjiDiagram` is a Drawable I've created from an SVG I pull from the app's Main Expansion File. The DialogFragment is super basic since all it needs to do is display the Drawable:

```
public class DialogStrokeOrder extends DialogFragment
{
    Drawable gStrokeDiagram;

    private static final String TAG = "DialogStrokeOrder";

    public static DialogStrokeOrder newInstance(Drawable diagram)
    {
        DialogStrokeOrder dso = new DialogStrokeOrder();
        dso.setDiagram(diagram);

        return dso;
    }

    public void setDiagram(Drawable diagram)
    {
        this.gStrokeDiagram = diagram;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(R.string.kanji_stroke_order);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_strokeorder, null);

        // Display the SVG
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.stroke_order_diagram);
        iv.setImageDrawable(gStrokeDiagram);

        builder.setView(layout);
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that, after rotation, the dialog is still visible but the diagram disappears. I *want* to preserve the Drawable by adding it to the `outState` Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`, but there's no "putDrawable()" method so I'm not sure what to do.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most common way to do this is to convert to a bitmap and to use putParcelable()

[How to Pass Drawable using Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070974/how-to-pass-drawable-using-parcelable)

Answer (score 0):

You could manage orientation changes yourself.  You can check out some discussion on this option [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).  Not exactly the solution you were requesting but may offer a better alternative than passing a drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to byte array and write to Parcelable, but the size can not too large,
that's will raise a exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could jam the drawable into a retained fragment or simply retain your current working fragment (although beware retained fragments do not play nice with the back stack).

Answer (score 0):

you can  conver  to  bitmap  and  after,  save  just  a  imagen,   then  load  that  image on  next  time.