# Sending ArrayList of drawables to Service (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with drawables and now I want to send them with an Intent to my Service class. How can I do it?
My ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Drawable> drawableList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
```

My Intent:

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, MyOwnService.class);
                service.putExtra("Dauer", dauer);
                service.putExtra("Links", false);
                startService(service);
```

I have Bitmaps which I convert to drawables:

```
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmp);
```

How can I put this ArrayList to this Intent?

Comment: there are all sorts of drawable. depending on what kind of drawables you are trying to send, a different method could apply. (-> please give more details)

Comment: You can try sending the ArrayList of integer reference of the drawable, like R.drawable.my_image

Comment: @njzk2 look Edit, AT Arman I dont have the drawables in any folder. The drawables are any Pictures the user chooses from his Gallery

Comment: You mean they are physical files in the device's storage?

Comment: @Lars3n95 : `the user chooses from his Gallery` In this case, you should consider passing the Uris to the pictures, rather than the actual drawable.

Answer (score 1):

The way you send messages within an Intent in Android is using the putExtra() method as you did. For the ArrayList you can create a class implementing the Parcelable interface. Here's an example:
[Arraylist in parcelable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704747/arraylist-in-parcelable-object)

Comment: But Drawable "is from Android" how can I let it implement Parelable then?

Comment: You could create some sort of inherited class which can be constructed  from an instance of Drawable

Comment: @Lars3n95, there is a way to parcel this class:See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070974/how-to-pass-drawable-using-parcelable. But maybe there is a better way of this. I think this must be time consuming..

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe simply pass the filenames in a list, so that the intent's receiver will load the files itself (if it can). That seems to be the simplest solution.

Another one would be to create a class that extends Drawable and that can be constructed from an instance of it and that implements the Parcelable interface (so that you can pass it using `putExtra()`)

Another solution that is widely used to tackle this problem but that looks quite ugly (at least to me): you can store your list in a static variable so that it can be accessed from another activity.