# How to pass a Drawable into a class?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Is there anyway to pass a `Drawable` through a class like so:

```
public loadImage(Context context, int drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawable);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

Trying to pass the `Drawable` into the class:

```
candyImg = new loadImage(getContext(), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.candy), 0, 0, 50, 50);
```

It says `getResources().getDrawable(drawable);` is deprecated. So how can I pass a `Drawable` through a class like so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070974/how-to-pass-drawable-using-parcelable

Comment: your `loadImage` method takes an `int` as the second parameter, not `Drawable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change `int drawable` parameter to `Drawable drawable`.

As of `getResources().getDrawable(drawable);` is deprecated, you need to replace it with `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_drawable)`.

As of `Context context` parameter is redundant, you can remove it:

```
public loadImage(Drawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.drawable = drawable;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}
```

Then, try to pass it into the class:

```
candyImg = new loadImage(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.my_drawable), 0, 0, 50, 50);
```